# Finding minimal polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $A\in M\underset{nxn}{(\mathbb{R})}$ so that $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{R}: A\neq \lambda I$. It also given that $A^4-5A^2+4I=A^3-7A-6I=0$.
Find the minimal polynomial.

I got the polynomial: $x^4-x^3-5x^2+7x+10=0$. After factorization I got:
$(x+2)(x+1)(x^2-4x+5)=0$.
I tried to find the minimal polynomial:
$(x+2)(A)= A+2I \Leftrightarrow A=-2I\rightarrow$ invalid since $A\neq \lambda I$.
$(x+1)(A)=A+I\Leftrightarrow A=-I\rightarrow$  invalid since $A\neq \lambda I$.
$(x^2-4x+5)(A)\rightarrow A^2-4A+5I=0\rightarrow$ irreducible since $F=\mathbb{R}$.
Therefore, the minimal polynomial must be: $(x+2)(x+1)(x^2-4x+5)$.

I am not sure if what I did is correct and how can I check it, can you please give me your way of solving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(A^4 - 5A^2 + 4I) - A(A^3 - 7A - 6I) = 0$. This gives you a $2$nd degree polynomial equation satisfied by $A$. Then use the conditions given to show that there's no first degree polynomial satisfied by $A$.

Comment: I did not fully understand what you did there, can you please explain it in a little more detail? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: $(A^4 - 5A^2 + 4I) - A(A^3 - 7A - 6I)$ is a second-degree polynomial which must be zero since $(A^4 - 5A^2 + 4I)$ and  $(A^3 - 7A - 6I)$ are. The minimal polynomial of $A$ therefore has to divide it. So either the minimal polynomial is this second-dgree polynomial, or it's one of its first-degree factors. Your given conditions will exclude the latter possibility.

Comment: Great! so it is basically $(x+2)(x+1)$ since we can't take either of them alone, but why the minimal polynomial must have to divide the new polynomial you've created? Is it had something to do with the fact that all polynomials that annihilates A forms an Ideal?

Comment: It's a principal ideal generated by the minimial polynomial, which is why the minimal polynomial divides any $p$ for which $p(A) = 0$.

Comment: Ok got it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Since $A^3=7A+6I$, you can replace $A^4$ by smaller powers of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if a polynomial $P$ annihilates a matrix $A$ then the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $P$ and then the spectrum of $A$ is includ in the set of roots of $P$.

We have

$x^4-5x^2+4=(x-1)(x-2)(x+2)(x+1)$ annihilates $A$ and then $\mathrm{sp}(A)\in\{1,2,-2,-1\}$

and

$x^3-7x-6=(x-3)(x+2)(x+1)$ annihilates $A$ and then $\mathrm{sp}(A)\in\{3,,-2,-1\}$

so 
 $$\mathrm{sp}(A)\in\{-2,-1\}$$
hence the minimal polynomial $\pi_A(x)=(x+2)(x+1)$ since otherwise $A=-2 I$ or $A=-I$.

Comment: one has to exclude things like $(x + 2)^2(x+1)$, $(x+1)(x+2)^2$, etc.

Comment: If a polynomial $P$ annihilates a matrix $A$ then the minimal polynomial divides $P$ so we exclude these things.

Comment: Why does what you wrote show $(x+2)(x+1)$ annihilates $A$?

Comment: In fact I showed that the polynomial $(x+2)(x+1)$ is the minimal polynomial so it annihilates $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So it must be (x+2)(x+1) since we can't take either of them alone, but why the minimal polynomial must have to divide the new polynomial you've created? Is it had something to do with the fact that all polynomials that annihilates A forms an Ideal?

Comment: Yes this exactly the fact and the minimal polynomial generates this ideal.

Comment: Ok. got it thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Consider the gcd of the two polynomials. Start by dividing the first by the second.